# styled jsx for Inferno in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, next.js, infernojs

How can I write definitions for Inferno.js

```
import 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface StyleHTMLAttributes<T> extends React.HTMLAttributes<T> {
    jsx?: boolean;
    global?: boolean;
  }
}
```

because

```
export const Footer = props =>
  <footer>
    <style jsx>{`{
      color: green;
    }`}</style>

  </footer>
```

causes an error.

> [ts] Property 'jsx' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLStyleElement>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by installing

`npm i --save-dev @types/styled-jsx`

It was tracked under this issue: https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx/issues/90